# Proper way to deal with class dependency in a custom class in Laravel 4

Tags: php, class, oop, laravel-4, dependencies

I'm adding a custom class to my Laravel library, and seem to be very close to success. Heres what I've done so far, followed by the error I'm getting:

My class is called Connector and is located in Acme/Api/Zurmo/Connector

This class requires another class, so this is the code for that:

```
use Acme\Api\Rest\ApiRestHelper;

class Connector implements ConnectorInterface {

    protected $rest;

    public function __construct(ApiRestHelper $rest)
    {
        $this->rest = $rest;
    }
```

and my ApiRestHelper class starts like this:

```
namespace Acme\Api\Rest;

class ApiRestHelper {
```

Then I've just added a quick closure in routes.php to test this works, (which it doesn't):

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $connector  = new Acme\Api\Zurmo\Connector;
    var_dump($connector); 
});
```

This is the error I get:

> Argument 1 passed to Acme\Api\Zurmo\Connector::__construct() must be
>   an instance of Acme\Api\Rest\ApiRestHelper, none given

I first assumed I'd screwed my namespacing, filenaming up, but Laravel can locate the class as I can do the following without error:

```
$rest = new Acme\Api\Rest\ApiRestHelper;
var_dump($rest);
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here? Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure Laravel has an autoloader

Comment: I think I'm almost there, however its too difficult to demonstrate in this comment so I think I will open a new question.

Comment: You can always edit your existing question

Answer (score 0):

The constructor expects you to pass in an instance of resthelper:

```
//manual dependency injection
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $connector  = new Acme\Api\Zurmo\Connector(new Acme\Api\Rest\ApiRestHelper);
    var_dump($connector); 
});
```

OR change the constructor

```
//creates a hard dependency
use Acme\Api\Rest\ApiRestHelper;

class Connector implements ConnectorInterface {

    protected $rest;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->rest = new ApiRestHelper();
    }
}
```

A more advanced option would be to use the IOC container for dependency inject, but thats beyond the scope of this answer

http://laravel.com/docs/ioc